# FLUTTER DOCTOR UBUNTU(Zorin OS) Summary shows the Problem Dart Path: Consider adding to front of Path

Tags: flutter, ubuntu, command-line, flutter-doctor

[FLutter Doctor Summary Problem in Ubuntu Zorin OS]

[image]

```
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on Zorin OS 16.2 5.15.0-76-generic, locale
    en_US.UTF-8)
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to /usr/bin/snap, which is not
      inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at
      /home/kamranhccpszorin/snap/flutter/common/flutter. Consider adding
      /home/kamranhccpszorin/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin to the front of
      your path.`
```